# Custom query with group by and then count

Tags: mysql

I am using events.I would like to know how to calculate sum in event or using single query
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad6d1c/1

DDL for question:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `in_use` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '0->in_use,1->not_in_use',
  `auto_assign` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0->Yes,1->No'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ALTER TABLE `table1`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `table1`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
INSERT INTO `table1` (`id`, `group_id`, `in_use`, `auto_assign`) VALUES
(1, 3, 1, 0),(2, 2, 0,1),(3, 1, 1, 1),(4, 3, 1, 0),(5, 3, 0, 0),(6, 3, 0, 1),
(7, 3, 1, 0),(8, 3, 0, 1),(9, 3, 0, 1),(10, 3, 0, 1),(11, 3, 0, 1),(12, 3, 1, 1),
(13, 3, 1, 0),(14, 3, 0, 0),(15, 3, 0, 0),(16, 3, 0, 0),(17, 3, 0, 0),(18, 3, 1, 1),
(19, 3, 0, 0),(20, 3, 0, 0)
```

Expected Output :

```
| count | in_use | auto_assign |  sum | check_count |
|-------|--------|-------------|------|------------ |
|     7 |      0 |           0 |  11  |     5       |
|     5 |      0 |           1 |  07  |     3       |
|     4 |      1 |           0 |  11  |     5       |
|     2 |      1 |           1 |  07  |     3       |
```

Here we can see that `auto_assign=0` have total `11` count(`7+4`) and 
`auto_assign=1` have `7` count(`5+2`) this count should be stored into new column `sum`.

`check_count` column is percentage value of `sum` column.Percentage will be predefined.

Lets take 50%, So count 11(sum column value) ->50% = 5.5 = ROUND(5.5) == 5(In integer). Same way count 7(sum column value)->50% = 3.5 =ROUND(3.5)=3(Integer)

Here `5 > 4(auto_assign=0 and in_use=1 )`.So have to insert record into another table(`table2`). if not then not.

Same way, If 3 >2 then also need to insert record into another table(`table2`).if not then not.

Note : This logic I would like to implement in `event`

This is bit complicated, but please suggest me how to do this in event.

Detail clarification :

here percentage_Value is `5` for `auto_assign =0`.But `auto_assign=0 and in_use=1` have `count` is `4` which `less than 5` ,then have to insert record into table 2.

suppose,if we get count is 6 for `auto_assign=0 and in_use=1` ,Then no need to insert record into `table2`.

Same way,

here percentage_Value is `3` for `auto_assign =1`.But `auto_assign=1 and in_use=1` have `count` is `2` which `less than 3` ,then have to insert record into table 2.

suppose,if we get count is 4 for `auto_assign=1 and in_use=1` ,Then no need to insert record into `table2`.

Insert query into table2:

```
Insert into table2(cli_group_id,auto_assign,percentage_value,result_value) values(3,0,5,4)
```

Comment: Thia is not a complete question because we can't see your data, and links may break over time.  Please include input data directly in the question.

Comment: I dont know how to include data directly in question.

Comment: What version of mySQL?  (8.0 has analytical functions which would make this easy.)

Comment: Mysql version is 5.6

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad6d1c/12/0)

Break the problem down: we need a count of the records by auto_Assigns; so we generate a derived table (B) with that value and join back to your base table on auto_Assign.  This then gives us the column we need for some and we use the truncate function and a division model to get the check_count

```
SELECT count(*), in_use, A.Auto_Assign, B.SumC, truncate(B.SumC/2,0) as check_Count
  FROM table1 A
  INNER JOIN (Select Auto_Assign, count(*) sumC 
              from table1 
              where Group_ID = 3
              Group by Auto_Assign) B
   on A.Auto_Assign = B.Auto_Assign
  WHERE GROUP_ID = 3
  Group by in_use, A.Auto_Assign
```

we can eliminate the double where clause by joining on it:

```
SELECT count(*), in_use, A.Auto_Assign, B.SumC, truncate(B.SumC/2,0) as check_Count
  FROM table1 A
  INNER JOIN (Select Auto_Assign, count(*) sumC, Group_ID
              from table1 
              where Group_ID = 3
              Group by Auto_Assign, Group_ID) B
   on A.Auto_Assign = B.Auto_Assign
   and A.Group_ID = B.Group_ID
  Group by in_use, A.Auto_Assign
```

I'd need clarification on the rest of the question: I'm not sure what 5 > 4 your'e looking at  and I see no 3 other than the check count but that's not "the same way"  so I'm not sure what you're after.

Here 5 > 4(auto_assign=0 and in_use=1 ).So have to insert record into another table(table2). if not then not.

Same way, If 3 >2 then also need to insert record into another table(table2).if not then not.

Note : This logic I would like to implement in event

This is bit complicated, but please suggest me how to do this in event.

So to create the event: [DOCS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html)

Which results in:

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 6 Minutes
DO
  INSERT INTO table2 
  SELECT count(*) as mCount
       , in_use
       , A.Auto_Assign
       , B.SumC, truncate(B.SumC/2,0) as check_Count
  FROM table1 A
  INNER JOIN (SELECT Auto_Assign, count(*) sumC, Group_ID
              FROM table1 
              WHERE Group_ID = 3
              GROUP BY Auto_Assign, Group_ID) B
     ON A.Auto_Assign = B.Auto_Assign
    AND A.Group_ID = B.Group_ID
  GROUP BY  in_use, A.Auto_Assign
```

Comment: Thanks for answer with expected output.But missing is how can i check output with foreach loop in event.Would you like to help with that ?

Comment: Not sure what you're after there, you'd need to clairify the question in that arena.  What is it you want going into table 2?  What would table 2 expected results look like?

Comment: I will add more clarification on it

Comment: I have added detail clarification about it.

Comment: Good detail but is this something that runs on a batch?  Is it a view against the result set that simply shows this information?  is the table2 even needed it's a view based on the results of the 1st query?

Comment: Actaully.I would like to create an event for it on every 360 seconds.I have around 6 types of events which are match some critearea and based on that create some traffic management.So in this case i can't create any view on table 2.Even from some places i am directly insert records into table2.